# Difference between date time field to check if its more or less than X minutes

Tags: django

I have a ticket model. I need to list out the tickets that are from a specific show, also which has been either bought or the time difference between now and `booked_at` is less than 5 minutes.

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    booked_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    bought = models.BooleanField(default=False)



unavailable = Ticket.objects.filter(show=show).filter(Q(bought=True) | Q(booked_at = ????))
```

How can I query for the difference between `now` and the `booked_at` field to check if its less/more than X minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__range` [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range) can be used to select model instances within a specified range, including dates and times.

Combine that with `datetime.timedelta` and you can pretty much write all you need:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

within_5_minutes = timezone.now() - timedelta(seconds=300)
unavailable = Ticket.objects.filter(
    show=show
).filter(
    Q(bought=True) | Q(booked_at__range=(within_5_minutes, timezone.now())
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
import datetime

booked_at__gt=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
```